# problems installing openvpn client

Tags: gnupg, openvpn

following the instructions on the official vpn page ([instructions install openvpn client](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/OpenVPN3Linux?_ga=2.250289542.1891781540.1634939723-1872440519.1634939723)) in the second step:

```
# curl -fsSL https://swupdate.openvpn.net/repos/openvpn-repo-pkg-key.pub | gpg --dearmor > /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/openvpn-repo-pkg-keyring.gpg
```

I get the following error message:

```
sudo curl -fsSL https://swupdate.openvpn.net/repos/openvpn-repo-pkg-key.pub | gpg --dearmor > /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/openvpn-repo-pkg-keyring.gpg
-bash: /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/openvpn-repo-pkg-keyring.gpg: Permission denied
(23) Failed writing body
```

Comment: Not really a programming problem so a bit "off" for this site, but the commands on that page seem to be designed to run at a root prompt, not using sudo.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, you are right. Have a nice sunday!!

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson your comment should be the answer!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I had a similar issue recently. Use

**`sudo wget https://swupdate.openvpn.net/repos/openvpn-repo-pkg-key.pub`**

and

**`sudo apt-key add openvpn-repo-pkg-key.pub`**

Reference -
https://openvpn.net/cloud-docs/openvpn-3-client-for-linux/

Comment: Hello Danny, <br/>
I would like to execute client linux openvpn: <br>
openvpn --config ~/.ssh/vpnbook-us1-tcp443.ovpn<br/>

Is it right?<br/>

I have found a file of type openvpn from book: <br/>
[link](https://www.vpnbook.com/)<br/>

Do I have to create my own file?<br/>
<br/>
I have seen the content of this type of file: <br/>
dev tun1<br/>
proto tcp<br/>
remote 198.7.62.204 443<br/>
remote us1.vpnbook.com 443<br/>
resolv-retry infinite<br/>
<br/>
How do I start the openvpn client in linux (ubuntu)? I already have everything installed<br/>
<br/>
Thanks in advance

Comment: sorry I do not know how I could put new lines in comments. Sorry!

Comment: Login to the VPN server page. There you have to download client.ovpn (User Lock Profile/Auto Login Profile) file from server. To connect the VPN, use the command, openvpn3 session-start --config path/to/client.ovpn

Comment: It isn't clear to me that these two commands above replace "curl -fsSL https://swupdate.openvpn.net/repos/openvpn-repo-pkg-key.pub | gpg --dearmor > /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/openvpn-repo-pkg-keyring.gpg" but this so far seems to work.  I haven't tried using the OpenVPN Client yet, though, so take that with a grain of salt.

Comment: I'm seeing this message - `Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).`

Comment: Unable to locate package openvpn3 - even after doing this. Anyone know how else to get openvpn3 on Ubuntu 20.04? Having the same issues as OP.

Comment: @alphabet5 and others using apt-key is outdated and insecure. Run the openvpn install commands via root, not sudo.

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial you posted is still valid, but as it was pointed out in the comments, you have to run the commands as superuser (I just tested `sudo` but it wouldn't work either).

Moreover, `apt-key` is mostly deprecated, so be careful with the accepted solution. If you follow the steps there, you will get a deprecation warning every time you run `apt update`.